# Application "would like to control this computer using accessibility features" despite already being allowed to do so

Tags: applications, settings

I recently updated to the latest macOS Ventura security patch. Ever since I did so, attempting to start Barrier prompts me with a dialog stating

> **"Barrier" would like to control this computer using accessibility features.**
> Grand access to this application in Privacy & Security settings, located in System Settings.

With options for "Open System Settings" and "Deny" (no "Allow").

In System Settings, Barrier is already listed with the "Allow" option enabled. Disabling and re-enabling Barrier does not dissuade macOS from showing me the dialog instead of launching the application. Removing Barrier from the list (with the `-` button) and re-adding it also doesn't seem to change anything.

How can I convince macOS to let me run this application, as I was prior to the macOS update installation?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem and I found a workaround.
Open a terminal and from there open Barrier with:

`/Applications/Barrier.app/Contents/MacOS/barrier >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

macOS will tell you that "Terminal" or "iTerm" (in my case) would like to control your mac using accessibility features. This time it will let you enable the permission and if you open it again it will work.

It's not the best way to do it but at least it works.